# K-NN Algorithm: Consistent Errors that pop up when certain code is entered

Tags: r

I am trying to create a K-NN model for a dataset and I keep on getting an error. How do I fix this given the following input:

```
library(kknn)
model <- kknn(y ~ ., train = train, k = 5)

# Error in model.matrix(mt2, test) : argument "test" is missing, with no default
```

I tried this also:

```
knn_model <- knn(train = df_train[, -1], test = df_test[, -1], cl = df_train$Creditability, k = 5)
```

then I got this error:

```
# Error in knn(train = df_train[, -1], test = df_test[, -1], cl df_train$Creditability,  : 'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

I'm not too sure which code I should use.

Comment: Adding `library(?)` would be useful...

Comment: Please run `dput()` on the data you are using and update your question with the result. This will help others to solve your issue. Thanks